# How to configure xubuntu panel network to a specifc network interface

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, network-monitoring

Please consider the picture below. I have installed the xfce widget for network load monitoring but in the settings there is no option to select which network adapter is uses. By occasion, system has select one of non-active interfaces.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a *dropdown* with network interfaces selection and have overseen the input field. I needed though to lookup the connection wihh `ifconfig` as the UI network monitor was showing a verbose message like "cable connection #3"

In the picture it's the freetext input field *Netzwerkschnittstelle*.

So I pasted the adapter name like `abc1234abcdef` and now it works!